# Create a TopMost non-transparent click-through toggle-able window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a wpf application and need to make a window that can be click-through when a certain variable is true or function is called (you can choose which one). The window has to still be visible however and is also TopMost.

I've looked on the internet and found a few Threads with similar questions, however these were all either old or for winforms not wpf. I did try them however and they did not seem to work for me.

Currently I am trying  this inside of the PluginHostView.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ModOS_wpf.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PluginHostWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PluginHostView : Window
    {
        public PluginHostView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Topmost = true;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
        public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
        public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetLayeredWindowAttributes")]
        public static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hWnd, int crKey, byte alpha, LWA dwFlags);

        protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnContentRendered(e);
            int wl = GetWindowLong(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, GWL.ExStyle);
            wl = wl | 0x80000 | 0x20;
            SetWindowLong(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, GWL.ExStyle, wl);
            SetLayeredWindowAttributes(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, 0, 128, LWA.Alpha);
        }

        public enum GWL
        {
            ExStyle = -20
        }

        public enum WS_EX
        {
            Transparent = 0x20,
            Layered = 0x80000
        }

        public enum LWA
        {
            ColorKey = 0x1,
            Alpha = 0x2
        }
    }
}
```

However this does not seem to be changing the window at all. This way seems to be the most popular and seems to work for most people. Also, this wouldn't allow for toggling of the click-through behavior if it worked.

I expected this to work however it didn't do anything.

If you want to completely change the way I am doing things, go ahead

**EDIT:**
Since it wasn't clear what the desired end result is here is a hopefully more clear explenation:

The window is top most (ontop of every other window, I already now how to do this part (just set TopMost=true in the constructor)), visible like it normally is but it doesn't interact with my mouse and all mouse events go straight trough it to the programs behind it. just like it was never there (Don't know how to do this)

Comment: I really don’t have a clear idea what it is you’re trying to do. Can you maybe provide a screenshot of the desired end-state?

Comment: A screenshot wouldn't really help since it doesn't display the click-through behaviour however I can try to explain it more clearly:

The window is top most (ontop of every other window), visible like it normally is but it doesn't interact with my mouse and all mouse events go straight trough it to the programs behind it. just like it was never there

Comment: Ok, that sounds like you’re looking for something similar to an html div with pointer-events: none. Such a thing is likely not easily possible in Windows as pointer events are transmitted to the window they are given to. It would be difficult to change this. The reason I asked for a graphic is that this is a request that does not make sense to me. Instead, I’d like to know what you are trying to accomplish and possibly suggest an alternative approach that doesn’t rely on impossibilities.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the `IsHitTestVisible` property on your Window to False or True whether you want to click though

Comment: Ok that disables me clicking on the window but it doesn't click through. Also, it doesn't disable clicking on the windows border which I guess I could remove when I want it to be click through

Comment: If you want to make the window ignore all input I suggest you look a bit more into window handles, your might, no almost definitely will be able to find your answer, but it will take time...